# Red shift and the expanding universe pertaining to gravity wells

Tags: gravity, cosmology, space-expansion, gravitational-redshift, redshift

is it possible that gravity's effect on the energy level of light could be causing the red shift in light arriving from other galaxies and not an expanding universe? it is impossible, after all, to truly measure light speed or to take any measurement without being within the confines of some sort of gravity well be it the earth, solar, or galactic gravity well.

Answer (score 0):

In short, no.

It is true that light will redshift/blueshift when exitting/entering (respectively) a gravitational potential well (this is observable and one may predict the amount of redshift expected....look up the Integrated Sach's Wolfe Effect), but this is a minor perturbation away from the dominant cause of the redshifting of light that we observe.

For the sake of argument, let us consider a universe that is static (e.g. not expanding). If light were redshifted due to leaving a potential well, that means light from galaxies would redshift as that light travels away from the stars where that light originates from, and enters intergalactic space. As that light approaches our galaxy, it would blueshift as it travels into our galaxy (and towards Earth where it is eventually observed). In this hypothetical, one may immediately expect three effects to be observable.

1.) the amount of redshift should be proportional to the mass of the galaxy (e.g. light from heavier galaxies is more redshifted)

2.) light from galaxies less massive than the Milky Way should be overall blue shifted (since the light redshifted some amount as it left its host galaxy, but blue shifted more when it encountered our galaxy)

3.) if we look at a galaxy, we would expect the light to be more redshifted towards the centre and less redshifted towards the outer edges (e.g. less of a potential well to climb out of)

We don't observe any of these effects. Redshift (almost entirely) scales with distance, not mass. The only blue shifted galaxies are found in our local neighbourhood where peculiar motions within our cluster dominate over the expansion of space (in other words within our cluster the scales are not big enough yet to have the expansion be the dominant contributor to the motion of galaxies). The third effect I mentioned technically should occur in our universe but is not significant (e.g. the effect would be very minor, possibly unobservably small....it is possible to calculate the magnitude of this effect). If redshift were due to light exitting/entering gravitational potential well, then would this effect to be much more pronounced.
Cheers.